# Get count of documents missing a field over a date histogram in ElasticSearch?

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch

I'm  trying to find out the number of documents that don't contain a certain field grouped daily.

The idea being that I can work out the daily response rate statistic.

I'm using PHP but can happily convert a JSON query to a suitable nested array.

Here's what I have so far.

```
$params['aggs'] = [
                "daily"=> [
                    "date_histogram"=> [
                        "field" => "date_created",
                        "interval" => "1d",
                        "min_doc_count" => 0
                    ],
                    "aggs"=>[
                        "unresponded"=>[
                            "missing"=>[
                                "field"=> "responses"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
```

This returns data, with an `unresponded` bucket for each `daily` bucket as expected, however the values don't tally up with the data. Instead every document that is in the `daily` bucket is accounted for in the `unresponded` bucket regardless of whether documents from that particular day have a `response` field or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `missing` aggregation doesn't work for existing but empty array fields. I had to rework the aggregation to make use of a boolean must-not exist.

```
"aggs"=>[
    "responded"=>[
          "filter"=>[
               "query"=>[
                   "bool"=>[
                       "must_not"=>[
                           "exists"=>[
                               "field"=>"responses"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
           ]
      ]
]
```